# Mathematical function, unassigned variables?

Tags: python, function, unassigned-variable

I am looking for a way to add together multiple mathematical functions before assigning the numerical values for the variables in the equations.
I am doing it this way because I need to optimize my code, and I want to assign different values to the variables each time.  An example of what I am trying to do:

1. `f(x, y) = x + 2y`
2. `g(x, y) = 3x - y`
3. adds `f(x, y) + g(x, y)` to get `h(x, y)`, so `f(x, y) + g(x, y) = h(x, y) = 4x + y`
4. Now that I have `h(x, y)`, I need multiple values from `h(x, y)`

```python
x = 4; y = 3, h(x, y) = 19
x = 1, y = 0, h(x, y) = 4
```

etc.

Is this possible?  I was trying to create them as strings, add the strings, then remove the quotes to evaluate the sum but this did not work.  I am trying to do my method this way because I want to optimize my code.  It would help very much if I am able to create my final function before evaluating it (it would be `h(x, y)` in this case).

EDIT: I'm doing additions of (e ** (x + y)), so linear solutions using matrices don't work :/

Comment: You are basically looking for a parser. Check out [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)  - python's version of lex and yacc

Comment: Even with e**(x+y), a matrix solution might work for cases where the exponential can be transformed appropriately. e.g. e**(x+y) == e**x * e**y so, if each of the terms is a vector, the two vectors could be multiplied together, giving a much faster solution than I expect `sympy` could give. For the general case where there isn't an appropriate transformation, though, @unutbu's solution is very attractive.

Comment: How would I use matrices to do this?  I'm working with equations that might look like...
e^ipi(4x - 2y) + e^ipi(10x + 3y) + e^ipi(x + 24y)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) can do this:

```
import sympy as sym

x, y = sym.symbols('xy')
f = x + 2*y
g = 3*x - y
h = f + g
```

This shows that [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) has simplified the expression:

```
print(h)
# y + 4*x
```

And this shows how you can evaluate `h` as a function of `x` and `y`:

```
print(h.subs(dict(x=4, y=3)))
# 19
print(h.subs(dict(x=1, y=0)))
# 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If the functions are all linear combinations of the variables, as shown in the examples, there is no need for a parser or the sympy solution suggested by @unutbu (which seems to be absolutely the right answer for complicated functions).

For linear combinations, I'd use `numpy` arrays to contain the coefficients of the variables, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array([1,2])
g = np.array([3,-1])
h = f + g
x = np.array([4,3])
sum(h*x)
```

... which gives the answer `19`, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lambda functions.

```
f=lambda x,y:x+2*y
g=lambda x,y:3*x-y
h=lambda x,y:f(x,y)+g(x,y)
```

and evaluate `h(x,y)`