# Calculating strings as values

Tags: python, string

Is it possible in Python to calculate a term in a string?
For example:

```
string_a = "4 ** (3 - 2)"

unknown_function(string_a) = 4
```

Is this possible? Is there a function that mimics "unknown_function" in my example?

Comment: For all that is right in the world, don't use Python (as in, `eval()` or using the parser or whatever) to parse this kind of thing. It is a security risk, and a bad idea. What you want is something that parses maths equations and solves them. Find a tool for that job and use it, don't hack something that happens to mostly do that job and try and make it do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is `eval`

```
eval(string_a)
# 4
```

But **do not use this under any circumstances** if `string_a` comes from anyone but you, because they can [easily hack into your system and destroy your files!](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the security risks. Perhaps he could filter out only math operands, parentheses, and number.

Comment: @Vreality That will only sort out simple attacks.

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, I was only giving an example. Is there a built in function to strip all non math related commands?

Comment: @Vreality My point is it's still a bad idea. It's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: AFAIK, you can do this "safely" using:  `eval(strina_a if '__' not in string_a else 'None',{'__builtins__':None})` although, as far as `eval` goes, you can never be 100% sure.

Comment: ... waiting for the firestorm that my last comment has the potential of igniting ...

Comment: @Anorov -- Could you please expand on what that supposedly dangerous code is supposed to do?  If you put that in a string and try to `eval` it, It looks like a SyntaxError to me ...

Comment: Alright, at this time I am not able to bypass your solution. My solution used Python's hex-escape string literal syntax; the same could be done with octal escapes or Unicode escapes. These still result in the same bytes that "__" corresponds to though, so there will not be a SyntaxError but your double underscore check will still detect it.

Comment: @mgilson I successfully found a bypass, though with some stipulations. At the least it is able to successfully bypass your "safe eval" function. See the following pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ke3jVve6 If you add another check to ensure only the very first line of the string is eval'd, I imagine it'd be much harder to find a workaround.

Answer (score 15):

Just like `sympy` was a useful module for your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668495/mathematical-function-unassigned-variables), it can apply here:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.sympify("4**(3-2)")
4
```

and even

```
>>> sympy.sympify("2*x+y")
2*x + y
>>> sympy.sympify("2*x+y").subs(dict(x=2, y=3))
7
```

Note though that this will return `sympy` objects, and if you want to get an integer or a float out of it you should do the conversion explicitly:

```
>>> type(sympy.sympify("4**(3-2)"))
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Integer'>
>>> int(sympy.sympify("4**(3-2)"))
4
```

I hacked together a recipe to turn string expressions into functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734176/487339) which is kind of cute.

Comment: You just know all the cool libraries don't you?  I guess that's what we get for having a (former?) computational astrophysicist around ...

Comment: +1 I think this should be the accepted answer; it does exactly what's needed, minus the security risk.

Comment: @musical_coder: I'm not sure about the absence of security risk.  I think `sympy` uses `eval` somewhere along the code path.

Comment: Yikes; I'll have to dig through the source code. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `eval` function.

```
>>> string_a = "4 ** (3 - 2)"
>>> eval(string_a)
4
>>>
```

You can read more in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 2):

There is a module `py-expression-eval`, that does not depend on the use of eval. It can be used to evaluate strings as a mathematical expression, even symbolic expressions can be evaluated.

```
from py_expression_eval import Parser
parser = Parser()

expr = parser.parse("4 ^ (3 - 2)")
expr.evaluate({})
```

For the use with symbolic expressions see:https://axiacore.com/blog/mathematical-expression-evaluator-python/